# Using $ notation for multiple column names: RStudio Autocompletion

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

Is there any way to address multiple R columns using $ notation?

e.g. Take this idiom:

```
aggregate(d[, 3:4], list(d$Name), mean)
```

Instead of remembering what cols 3 & 4 are it would be more expressive to use column names. Now this works:

```
aggregate(d[,c("Claimed.Amount","Paid.Amount")], list(d$Name), mean)
```

My only problem is the convenience of autocompletion is lost. RStudio auto completes on column names after a $ sign but not within strings. Many of my data frames have long column names & it is hard to not make mistakes typing them out manually.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

which version of Rstudio are you using? In Version 0.99.896, you can write `mtcars[,c()]` and autocomplete column names inside `c()`

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for that tip. My mistake was I was opening the string inside c() and then pressing the Tab key for auto-completion. If I press it right after I start c() it works! That's awesome! Thanks again!

Comment: Also possible without `c()`: `mtcars[,]`and "TAB" after the comma.